# Assembly script 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof Array'

Tags: arrays, nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I am reading the document about [the smart contract in Near in Assembly Script](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro#:%7E:text=var%20arr%20%3D%20Array.create%3Cstring%3E(10)%3B). When reading about the Arrays in it. It said "there is two why to initialize an array"

1. `var arr = new Array<string>(10);`
2. `var arr = Array.create<string>(10);`

when I am trying the second option with create it gives me the following error:

`Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof Array`

can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three different ways to instantiate Arrays in AssemblyScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966406/three-different-ways-to-instantiate-arrays-in-assemblyscript)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the documentation on NEAR should be updated, because according to [The AssemblyScript Book](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/array.html#constructor), an array is created using your first example. The second example [(using .create) is deprecated](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/pull/855/files)

From the docs

```as
var arr = new Array<string>(10)
// arr[0]; // would error 
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  arr[i] = ""
}
arr[0]; // now it works
```

Answer (score -1):

(edited)
Try this line:

```
let testData = new Array<string>()
let data = Array.create<string>(10)
```

Try this way and let me know if its works!

[Information link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966406/three-different-ways-to-instantiate-arrays-in-assemblyscript)

Comment: I do try it but it still give me the same error.

Comment: Okey, please try this I found: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966406/three-different-ways-to-instantiate-arrays-in-assemblyscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966406/three-different-ways-to-instantiate-arrays-in-assemblyscript)

Comment: let me know if this works! Thank you.

Comment: thanks.
 I read that link they write as an update that "Array.create deprecated and should not be used anymore."  So I think I will stick with the first option and fill the element to the required length.